# How can a PHP extension be installed if php.ini does not exist?

Tags: php, webserver, php.ini

I'm using [Uniform Server](http://www.uniformserver.com) and [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) for a project. It is for personal use, so it is restricted to my machine. Uniform Server came with Apache 2.4.25, PHP 7.1.1, phpMyAdmin 4.6.6, and MySQL 5.6.35-community.

MediaWiki wants an extension called `fileinfo`. According to the installation instructions, I have to remove the semicolon from the beginning of the line referencing `php_fileinfo.dll` in the `php.ini` file. However, `php.ini` doesn't exist. Is it possible to install `fileinfo` without using `php.ini`?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not create php.ini?

Comment: How does one do that?

Comment: well personally I would use `vi` but you use whatever editor you want...

Comment: Sorry, I meant "what is the structure of the file and what do I do with it?" I've never worked with PHP.

Comment: The PHP installation should come with a couple of sample ini files named `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`. Simply copy one of those and name it php.ini. Since you are using it for development the ini-development sample is probably a good choice.

Comment: I found something called `php_development.ini`. It would appear that this is file the installation instructions wanted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the `php_development.ini` file and renaming it `php.ini` worked.